# Is there any possibility to make my local machine as master/slave to access Jenkins myself without depending on any other machines

Tags: jenkins

I wanna execute jobs from my local machine by accessing jenkins page thru URL which can be active if master/slave machine is unlocked and batch files of Jenkins and SonarQube ran successfully. Now the issue I am facing is due to work from home i cannot go and unlock the machine which is available in office so that tried unlocking thru remote/VM. still not able to execute the jobs successfully. getting error like,

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "TechTalk.SpecFlow" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. [C:\Jenkins\workspace\RegistrationSanity\RegressionTestSuite\BatchDataManager\BatchDataManager.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "xunit.assert" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. [C:\Jenkins\workspace\RegistrationSanity\RegressionTestSuite\BatchDataManager\BatchDataManager.csproj]

```
2 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:09.99
[RegistrationSanity] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\AUTOMA~1.EMI\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins7061082824491969029.bat

C:\Jenkins\workspace\RegistrationSanity>"C:\Jenkins\workspace\RegistrationSanity\RegressionTestSuite\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.1\tools\net452\xunit.console" "C:\Jenkins\workspace\RegistrationSanity\RegressionTestSuite\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll" -trait "Description=Deductions - Re-register Option Validation - Inbox" -trait "Description=Amendment - Delete Option Validation - Inbox" -trait "Description=Add Private Patient --- passed from local" 
xUnit.net Console Runner (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: Tests
  Discovered:  Tests
  Starting:    Tests
-> Using app.config
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5
Could not send keyboard input. ErrorCode: 5

Kindly help me to resolve the problem. If possible suggest me with any other solution. 
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the agent setup of local machine with Jenkins Master, Find it here : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows
https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-03-configure-master-and-slave

And in your job mention that on which agent / node the build or stage should execute.

If you are using pipeline script you can set the node[local machine after setup] or you should have Jenkins job type where you can set the agent.

If you are working in corporate, probably you need admin access to [Administrator can] do this setup in Jenkins master.

Hope it helps

-Madhan

Comment: Thank you Madhan. it helped me to get some ideas.